# How to use nlapiXMLToPDF within a suitelet

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

Currently using Suitescript 1.0 to create a mail merge pdf generator. This is how I've structured it - there are 4 scripts (1 user event, 1 client script and 2 suitelets).
The user-event script generates a drop-down menu showing all available templates on whatever record it's deployed to.

```
function beforeLoad(type, form){

  var folderId = "folderId";
  var filters = new Array();
  filters[0] = new nlobjSearchFilter('internalid', null, 'is', folderId);
  
  var columns = new Array();
  var filename = new nlobjSearchColumn('name', 'file');
  var file_id = new nlobjSearchColumn('internalid', 'file');
  
  
  var fieldId = "custpage_mail_merge_dropdown";
  var fieldLabel = "Mail Merge Dropdown";
  

  var select = form.addField(fieldId, 'select', fieldLabel);

  columns[0] = filename;
  columns[1] = file_id;
  
  var searchResults = nlapiSearchRecord('folder', null, filters, columns);
  if(searchResults){
    for(var i = 0; i < searchResults.length; i++){
      var f = searchResults[i];
      //add values to the dropdown field created earlier in the UI
      
      select.addSelectOption(f.getValue(file_id), f.getValue(filename))
    }
  }

}
```

[image: Dropdown generated by code]

The purpose of the client script is to act as a mediator between the both suitelets and the record on which it has been deployed.

```
function verifyList(types, name, linenum){  
    
  
    if(name == 'custpage_mail_merge_dropdown'){
      
      var field = nlapiGetField(name);
      
      var fileName = nlapiGetFieldText(name);
      var suiteletUrl = nlapiResolveURL("SUITELET", script_id_1, 1);
      var response = nlapiRequestURL(suiteletUrl+"&fileName="+fileName);
      var fileContent = "";
      if(response.getBody()){
        fileContent = response.getBody();      
        nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'STATUS', 'Client script activated '+ JSON.stringify(fileContent));
        var renderedFile = ejs.render(fileContent, {});
        var suiteletPdfUrl = nlapiResolveURL("SUITELET", script_id_2, 1);
        var response2 = nlapiRequestURL(suiteletPdfUrl+"&ejsCompiled="+renderedFile);
        
        nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'STATUS', 'Client script activated '+ JSON.stringify(renderedFile));
        
      }

    }  

}
```

The purpose of the first suitelet is to load and return the template selected from the dropdown to the client, where it is transformed using the ejs.render()

**SUITELET 1**

```
function mail_merge(req, res){
  
  var fileName = req.getParameter('fileName');
  
  if(fileName){
    var fileId = "Templates__/"+fileName;
    var load_file = nlapiLoadFile(fileId);
    var fileContent = load_file.getValue();
    res.write(fileContent);
    nlapiLogExecution("DEBUG", "STATUS", "Suitelet script activated : "+fileName);
  }  

  
}
```

The second suitelet (is supposed to) facilitate/s the creation of the PDF document based on the transformed content from the first suitelet which was passed to the client script.
**SUITELET 2**

```
function pdf_mail_merge(req, res){
    

    var ejsCompiled = req.getParameter('ejsCompiled');
    //Split by </pdf> due to unexpected string tagging along with file content
    ejsCompiled = ejsCompiled.split("</pdf>")[0];
    ejsCompiled +="</pdf>";
    if(ejsCompiled){
      nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'STATUS', "EJS Compiled "+ejsCompiled);
      try{
      var pdf_file = nlapiXMLToPDF(ejsCompiled);
      }catch(err){
        nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'STATUS', err);
      }
      res.setContentType("PDF", "somename.pdf");
      res.write(pdf_file.getValue());
      nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'STATUS', "Second script activated "+JSON.stringify(pdf_file))
    }  
  
    
  }
```

On selecting an option from the dropdown, I'm greeted with this message:
"An unexpected error occurred in a script running on this page... UNEXPECTED_ERROR"

This is the template used for testing. This is exactly the string that nlapiXMLToPDF will take as an argument.

```
<pdf>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Template One</h1>
    </body>
</pdf>
```

This is what baffles me, the string seems to be perfectly fine to me yet I keep getting this strange error. If any of you could provide any insight into what the problem might be, it would be much appreciated. Please forgive my lengthy post, I thought it would be useful to post most of the code being used to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your templates are missing the XML and DOCTYPE declarations that the BFO template engine requires (see page 8 of the [BFO User Guide](https://bfo.com/products/report/docs/userguide.pdf)).

Try adding the following at the beggining of the template string:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE pdf PUBLIC "-//big.faceless.org//report" "report-1.1.dtd">
```